# How can I figure out cordless drill terminal polarities?

Tags: electrical, battery

[image]
I just got this Black and Decker SS18 drill and wanted to run it with my existing batteries but the drill has no polarity markings. Anyway to figure out which terminal is which?

Comment: What brand is it?  Manufacturers have a habit of making their batteries physically incompatible, so not sure what your plan is for that.

Comment: It's a Black and Decker SS18, and I was thinking I could 3d print an adapter.

Comment: If there's a will there's a way! I converted my daughter's 12v slow as f... car into an 18v Makita, did the same for my son's 12v motorcycle, LED flood light, ryobi weed trimmer and others. I made my son's remote control Nerf tank a 12v milwaukee. Oh and I converted the Makita Jobsite radio into a charger/radio added bluetooth, extra power outlets and USB charging points.

Comment: God help me if I get my hands on a 3D printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on an [Instructables article](https://www.instructables.com/id/Cheap-Black-Decker-18Volt-battery/) about rebuilding a Black and Decker battery, it would appear they have chosen to use the outside terminal for positive and the inner terminal for negative.

[image]

In another part of the article, he shows another brand of battery that has a very similar terminal but the connectors are in a different position.  It's easy enough to just move the terminals as needed.

Of course, this might not be true for 100% of the B&D line, but it's pretty good evidence.